# cannot use add-Migration in .net core 2.1 project using visual studio for mac

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio for Mac and have .NET Core 2.1 project. I have an issue when using any migration command like "Add-Migration", namely the following error occurs:

```
**Add-Migration : The term ‘Add-Migration’ is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
 + Add-Migration DBUpdates -Context applicationdbcontext
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo         : ObjectNotFound: (Add-Migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**
```

Any clue what the cause of this could be?

Comment: `Add-Migration` is from EF 6, not from EF Core, so it makes complete sense that it doesn't work. Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-add

Comment: You need to add the correct nuget package. Believe it’s entity framework core tools

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if called in visual studio, add-migration is correct in EF Core. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs

Comment: @ahmedGaber. A you running add-migration from visual studio or from command line?

Comment: thanks for your response @Julian from visual studio and now woking after uninstall and install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that one package is missing.

Install package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` from nuget. Then **reopen** the visual studio.

Comment: uninstall and then install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and restart visual studio resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the nuget package, if thats not the case also double check you have the powershell interface in Visual Studio pointing at the correct project (You want the one where your DbContext object exists and is defined)

[image]